# Importance of the distinguished point/point at infinity of an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

To paraphrase the definition given in Katz and Mazur's "Arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves", an elliptic curve over a base scheme $S$ is a pair of a group scheme $f: E \to S$ that is a smooth curve over $S$, together with a distinguised $S$-point/section:
$$\infty: S \to E$$
such that all geometric fibres $E_s$, i.e. all pullbacks:
$$E_s := E \times_{s, S, f} \mathrm{Spec} (k_s)$$
are curves of genus $1$ over $k_s$ (note that the arithmetic and geometric genera agree), wherein $k_s$ is the residue field at some point $s \in S$.

My question is then, why is the point $\infty$ needed to define an elliptic curve ? Alternatively, are there examples of genus 1 curves that are not elliptic ? Thank you.

Comment: Even over a field ($S$ is a field), all smooth cubic plane curves have genus one, but unless it has a rational point (this corresponds to your infinity section), it is not an elliptic curve.

Comment: If someone were to hand you a smooth projective curve of genus one, what would its group law be? What even would be the identity? You do not really have an elliptic curve with a group law!

Comment: @TokenToucan But $E$ is already a group scheme. Why would a point at infinity be needed to define the group law ?

Comment: @DatMinhHa yes but in your last question you did not assume you already had a group scheme. And even if you do, as the other comment indicates, you need this point to be defined over the ground field in order for the group law to be as well.